# Combining formulas using AND

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to combine two forumlas into one.

They both work individually and I would like to make it so the condition is only met if both formulas are met. The forumlas are:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet2!$C$6>40,Sheet2!$C$6<=50),TRUE,FALSE)


=IF((INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","3"))>=Sheet2!$B$6),TRUE,FALSE)
```

I have tried to use another AND clause but had no luck yet with this, would anyone be able to provide a consolidated formula for both of these?

Comment: what about : `=IF(AND(Sheet2!$C$6>40,Sheet2!$C$6<=50,INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","3"))>=Sheet2!$B$6),TRUE,FALSE)` ?

Comment: Wrapping both formulas within AND seems to work `AND(IF(),IF())`.

Comment: Note that all formulas of the form `=IF(XXX, TRUE, FALSE)` can be replaced by `=XXX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the long way:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet2!$C$6>40,Sheet2!$C$6<=50,INDIRECT("R3C"&COLUMN(),)>=Sheet2!$B$6), TRUE, FALSE)
```

the short way:

```
=AND(Sheet2!$C$6>40,Sheet2!$C$6<=50,INDIRECT("R3C"&COLUMN(),)>=Sheet2!$B$6)
```

also possible:

```
=((Sheet2!$C$6>40)*(Sheet2!$C$6<=50)*(INDIRECT("R3C"&COLUMN(),)>=Sheet2!$B$6))=1
```

why the `SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","3")`??? just `ADDRESS(3,COLUMN(),4)` will be the same... also why address at all? just`INDIRECT("R3C"&COLUMN(),)` will also work

Answer (score 0):

Compiling the comments, this should be the minimal formula gathering your tests :

```
=AND(Sheet2!$C$6>40,Sheet2!$C$6<=50,INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","3"))>=Sheet2!$B$6)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it comes up saying ' The formula you typed contains an error.' Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `=IF((INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","3"))>=Sheet2!$B$6),TRUE,FALSE)` works properly on its own? Because the rest seems just fine...

Comment: at `...COLUMN(),4‌​),"1"...` there are unknown characters between the `4` and the `)` this leads to an error

Comment: @DirkReichel : I don't get want you mean as I don't see anything between the `4` and `)`, could you explain?

Comment: copy paste it to the notepad and then move the cursor over that part (with the arrow keys)... there 2 symbols you cant see, but they are there

Comment: i dont know for sure why that symbols are there... but as far as i know, the "new line" (which consists of 2 symbols) will be split up and left the second part (which is simply invisible)... for me: this error pops up pretty often looking at java script (everything is written as one long line)... but... who knows for sure... ^^;

Comment: I was just comparing them as I thought I was going mad. How bizarre. Thanks both for your inputs, much appreciated